# The overall performance where the method is placed in a code

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
namespace FastReflectionTests
{
    public class Test
    {
        public void Method1()
        {
            var x = 10;
            var y = 20;
             if (x == 10 && y == 20)
            {

            }
        }

        public void Method2()
        {
            var x = 10;
            var y = 20;
            if (x == 10 && y == 20)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now consider the IL Code:

This is method1:

```
    instance void Method1 () cil managed 
    {
    // Method begins at RVA 0x3bd0
    // Code size 17 (0x11)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
    [0] int32 x,
    [1] int32 y
    )

    IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 10
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    IL_0003: ldc.i4.s 20
    IL_0005: stloc.1
    IL_0006: ldloc.0
    IL_0007: ldc.i4.s 10
    IL_0009: bne.un.s IL_0010

    IL_000b: ldloc.1
    IL_000c: ldc.i4.s 20
    IL_000e: pop
    IL_000f: pop

    IL_0010: ret
    } // end of method Test::Method1
```

This is method2:

```
    instance void Method2 () cil managed 
    {
    // Method begins at RVA 0x3bf0
    // Code size 17 (0x11)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
    [0] int32 x,
    [1] int32 y
    )

    IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 10
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    IL_0003: ldc.i4.s 20
    IL_0005: stloc.1
    IL_0006: ldloc.0
    IL_0007: ldc.i4.s 10
    IL_0009: bne.un.s IL_0010

    IL_000b: ldloc.1
    IL_000c: ldc.i4.s 20
    IL_000e: pop
    IL_000f: pop

    IL_0010: ret
    } // end of method Test::Method2
```

> method1 get 00:00:00.0000019 second for invoke.
>
> method2 get 00:00:00.0000006 second for invoke.

I write this code for test

```
public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Test();
            test.Method1();
            test.Method2();
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    public class Test
    {
        public void Method1()
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            var x = 10;
            var y = 20;
            if (x == 10)
            {
                if (y == 20)
                {

                }
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Time Method1: {0}",
                stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }

        public void Method2()
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            var x = 10;
            var y = 20;
            if (x == 10 && y == 20)
            {

            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time Method2: {0}",
                stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }
    }
```

I change the place of method1 and method2.

```
 test.Method2();
 test.Method1();
```

and re-run the test.

> method1 get 00:00:00.0000006 second for invoke.
>
> method2 get 00:00:00.0000019 second for invoke.

**When I change the place of methods, the second method spends more time than the first method! What is the reason?**

Comment: Wait, do you mean that the first method you **call** is slower? Because it seems like your second example output is the first one copy-pasted, not the result of you running your code after changing the order of *calls*. (It still lists `method1` before `method2`.) In that case, duh, on the second call its code is probably in the CPU cache or was JITted already.

Comment: Agree that the 2 methods have the same `calculations`, so the first call is always slower than the second because the `calculations` may be cached in CPU cache after the first call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're timing a *trivial* amount of code, in such a way that any number of tiny incidental things will be disturbing the results - a page fault or cache miss could become relevant at that point... and that could easily be affected by the ordering of methods.

You should really benchmark *multiple* calls - or any way of doing enough work to take a reasonable amount of time. Any benchmark which measures time less than a second or so is dubious, IMO.

Additionally:

- You almost certainly don't want to include JIT compilation time.
- JIT compilation should be able to remove code which is basically pointless, most of the time. I typically add some sort of accumulator and output the result at the end of the test (after stopping the `Stopwatch`) to keep the JIT compiler "honest".

See Eric Lippert's benchmarking series for more details (and other pitfalls like GC):

- [Part one](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one)
- [Part two](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two)
- [Part three](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1317/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-three)
- [Part four](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1433/performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-four)

Comment: I write a loop 0 to 100000 in the function and again get same result the first method get more time

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ A loop from 0 to 100000 that does nothing could be removed during optimisation.

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ: Does that happen if you call the methods twice? Bear in mind there's JIT compilation time as well... and optimization of a loop which does nothing useful, as millimoose has said. I suggest you edit your question with what you believe to be a *valid* test. You might want to read Eric Lippert's series on benchmarking, starting here: http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one

Comment: @JonSkeet Poking at this in IDEone I think the OP is just phrasing things badly and means that the first method that gets *called* is slower.

Comment: @millimoose: which is quite possibly to do with JIT compilation. That's the problem - there are enough perils in benchmarking that it's tricky to write a good one, and we need to see the complete code of what the OP considers "done" before it's really worth picking it apart too much.